# Terminating while loop in sybase stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, while-loop, sap-ase

Is there a statement like break that can terminate the while loop in stored procedure? I am now terminating by checking an additional condition but the whole loop have to be nevertheless completed atleast once to check the condition again. Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop does indeed have a `break` clause which exits the loop, and can be placed within a conditional.

The Sybase "[Transact-SQL Users Guide](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/title.htm)" (and other ASE reference documents) is a valuable resource which can be read on-line or downloaded as a PDF from the [Sybase](http://www.sybase.com/) website. The documentation area is currently named "Infocenter". The document set is updated for each release.

Here is an extract from the above-mentioned guide about `break` (and `continue`)...

> *break* and *continue* control the operation of the statements inside a *while* loop.
>   *break* causes an exit from the *while* loop. Any statements that appear after the
>   *end* keyword that marks the end of the loop are executed. *continue* causes the
>   *while* loop to restart, skipping any statements after *continue* but inside the loop.
>   *break* and *continue* are often activated by an if test.
>
> The syntax for break...continue is:

```
while boolean expression
begin
    statement
    [statement]...
    break
    [statement]...
    continue
    [statement]...
end
```